# Open a link in new tab, not working target='_blank'

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a *PHP* code, in need to open a link in new tab.

But i tried `target='_blank'` in all the areas not working.

```
return "<a href='".get_home_url()."/out/".$post->ID.
 "/".$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['code_link']."/' title='"
.$post->ID."' rel='nofollow' class='btn btn-primary cbtn'>"
.$CORE->_e(array('button'))."</a>";
```

I think its calling the link from `code_link` not sure exactly.

Comment: post HTML output, with target="_blank" and we'll see

Comment: Actually this link is called by a jQuery function. jQuery(".button").click(function {
    var url = "<?php echo get_home_url();  ?>

Comment: I tried adding target blank everywhere in that line, it didnt work :(

Comment: try to replace `rel='nofollow'` with `target="_blank"`. also post the actual html produced. the content of the `a`-element might sport a click handler that kills event propagation.

Comment: @collapsar tried it, not working

Comment: have you tested the expression with a verbatim url (eg. google.com) ?

Comment: you wrote you have an embedded click handler on `.button` elements. i assume, one of these buttons forms the content of the `a` tag. if it does, return `true` from within this handler.

Comment: @collapsar, where should i define true? What is the code.     <script type="application/javascript">    
                                 
        jQuery(".button").click(function (e) {
 var url = "<?php echo get_home_url();  ?>
        });

Comment: `jQuery(".button").click(function () { var url = "<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>"; return true; });`.

Comment: @collapsar Sorry forgot to mention the full line. Tried that return true not workin.                              var url = "<?php echo get_home_url();  ?>/?popup="+jQuery(this).attr('title');

Comment: the final space in your php section looks dubious, especially when followed by a query component (`/?popup=...`). btw can't you check/post the actual html generated by the interplay of php/js? or maybe post the complete javascript involved in link generation and event processing? it's near to impossible to provide substantial advice while seeing only fragments copy-pasted with clerical errors.

Answer (score 0):

The target="_blank" is a simple HTML attribute, and should work. The trick is to check to see if the attribute is present at "click time".

```
return "<a href='".get_home_url()."/out/".$post->ID.
   "/".$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['code_link']."/' title='"
   .$post->ID."' rel='nofollow' class='btn btn-primary cbtn' target='_blank'>"
   .$CORE->_e(array('button'))."</a>";
```

At run time, use a HTML debugging tool such as Firebug in Firefox, and inspect the link. Check to make sure the target attribute is still present. If it is not, you may have other javascript that is removing the attribute. This will be harder to diagnose and fix.

Answer (score 0):

in your
`jQuery(".button").click(function { var url = "<?php echo get_home_url(); ...`

use `window.open(url, '_blank');` instead of `window.location = url;`

[window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)
Take a note that opening target="_blank" links in new **Window** or **Tab** depends on the user browser settings.

Comment: Actually your solution worked, but this jquery is initializing a pop-up. and that pop-p is opening in new window. But the link is still opening in same window.

Answer (score -2):

If this link is "clicked" by jQuery, try

```
jQuery(".button").click(function { 

 var url = 'some php output';
 window.open(url);

});
```

or simply replace `href` on `$.ready` in all `.button` links

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 var url = 'some php output';
 jQuery(".button").attr('href', url);

});
```